# Подскажите способ решения олимпиадной задачи

Tags: олимпиада

*Вместо уроков информатики мальчик Вася занимался подготовкой к олимпиадам по программированию и достиг в этом больших успехов. К сожалению, в результате постоянных тренировок, Вася стал мыслить "внутри коробки". Например, увидев задачу, приведенную ниже, Вася подумал: "Хм, странно, где ограничения? Ладно, напишу длинную арифметику, точно пройдет. Так, что же выбрать? Обратную польскую нотацию или рекурсивный разбор выражения?...". Конечно же, задача решается намного проще, чем думает Вася, но для этого надо мыслить вне коробки. А ограничения можно узнать, посмотрев на входной файл, который прилагается к условию.*

*Задача формулируется так: Вам дан набор корректных арифметических выражений, в которых используются целые числа,математические операции
+ , − и ∗ и круглые скобки. Запись каждого выражения начинается со знака = . Для каждого из выражений посчитайте результат вычислений.*

[Вот тут](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/emCb/gXFkchRJ2) файл со входными данными. Сам долго искал какой-то подвох в задаче, который существенно упрощает решение, но так и не нашёл. Понимаю, что можно использовать ту самую ОПН, про которую сказано в условии, но задача должна решаться как-то проще - это ясно указано.

Comment: Ну первая "странность" данных, что в них нет двух открывающихся скобок подряд. только закрывающиеся. так что можно попробовать идти задом на перед, но приоритеты надо соблюдать ...

Comment: Все числа в пределах 100, больше 4 умножений нет - никакой длинной арифметики тут не надо.

Answer (score 1):

Реализация идеи из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489686/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8/490042#490042), только на `python3`:

```py
# Скачивание файла
import requests
rs = requests.get('https://cloclo18.datacloudmail.ru/weblink/view/emCb/gXFkchRJ2?etag=7706DA739680EAC4A5B9044E9767047365988F54&key=a91762c6f1d8a559f6d780934b2509c728b33df4')

# Получение текста, разделение его построчно, пронумерование
for i, line in enumerate(rs.text.split('\n'), 1):
    # Если строка пустая
    if not line:
        continue
    
    # Обрезание первого символа, удаление ' ', '\n', '\r' и т.п.
    line = line[1:].strip()
    print('{}. {} = {}'.format(i, line, eval(line)))
```

Консоль:

```
1. 1+97*98*5 = 47531
2. 39-56 = -17
3. 92*66 = 6072
4. 40+66 = 106
5. 95-80 = 15
...
69997. 11+8*28+(37) = 272
69998. 33+21-(16+(20)-(58)) = 76
69999. (64) = 64
70000. (26)*(59-(48)-(13-67)) = 1690
```

Answer (score 0):

Прочитать строку, заменить знак "равно" на порядковый номер строки и слово print. Сохранить полученный файл с расширением bas. Выполнить программу в интерпретаторе Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно решение «вне коробки»:

Строки в файле записаны в формате формул Microsoft Excel. Поэтому копируем файл в clipboard, открываем новый лист Excel, вставляем в первую колонку, выделяем первую колонку, копируем результат: http://pastebin.com/KdCy9nRg.

Comment: можно и без копирования, просто переименовать в .csv и открыть в excel =) специально перепроверил, работает =)

Comment: @минусатор: Извольте объяснить ваш минус.

Answer (score -1):

Операций не более 4. Т. е. даны 4 или менее операций и порядок их выполнения. Ну и никакой длинной арифметики.